# Why do my homemade tortillas turn hard at first but then become soft?

Tags: tortilla

I suppose this is more curiosity than a problem, but why do my homemade (corn) tortillas start hard as soon as they are off the pan and then quickly turn soft? They seem quite dry immediately after being cooked, but stacking them with a plate on top and bottom will the leave plate quite steamy (presumably more moisture being released from the tortillas). Again, after leaving them alone for a while they are softer and moister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the moisture is distributing throughout the tortilla. Same thing happens to bread when it's baked. The crust is hard but there is still a lot of moisture inside which will moisten and soften the crust. Your tortillas will also pick up moisture from the air when left out.